# PhpStorm How to change suggested colors when editing CSS files

Tags: css, colors, phpstorm, autosuggest

When editing the CSS file in PhpStorm (2016.2) it opens up the color suggestion box every time I add a line with al color, border, background-color and so on. The suggestion box seems to have lots of possible colors to select from.
How to limit that selection to only just those few that I already use in the project? Otherwise this suggestion box is useless suggesting hundreds of other colors.

Comment: It already does exactly that: it shows colors from all (?) CSS files in your project (including .sass/.scss/.less). Using latest PhpStorm 2021.1.4 version though.

Comment: You can check it all this way: select the color that IDE suggests and now od the project wide search in all files (`Find in Path` functionality) -- it should show all places where that color is used. **P.S.** Note the possible difference in letter case (e.g. `ff11cc` vs `FF11CC`); the short/long form (`fff` vs `ffffff`). I'm not sure that different color system/scheme (e.g. `HSL` vs `RGB`) or darken/lighten color functions (CSS preprocessors have functions for color manipulations) will be reflected here.

Comment: Another example: create a brand new empty project, place 1 css file there that you know what colors it uses. Now check what colors are suggested when you write your new CSS code.

Comment: Thank you #LazyOne - You are right. I must have missed the fact the some of the plugins (wordpress template development) introduced hundreds of colours in their own CSS files.